# NPOI corrupted files when creating or appending data

Tags: c#, npoi

I'm trying to create an *.xlsx* file using *NPOI* in a C# application. I'm getting some weird errors that I did not initially get. The first few times I tested this code I received a MissingMethod exception. I tried to search for an explanation but everything that was suggested failed (including removing the package folder and re-loading all of the packages).

This is my WriteExcel method:

```
public void WriteExcel()
        {
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(workingDirectory + @"\Excel");
            var newFile = workingDirectory + @"\Excel\data.xlsx";

            try
            {
                if (Directory.Exists(workingDirectory + @"\Excel"))
                {
                    if (!File.Exists(newFile))
                    {
                        using (var fs = new FileStream(newFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
                        {
                            IWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
                            ISheet sheet = workbook.CreateSheet("Data");
                            IRow row = sheet.CreateRow(0);
                            ICell cell1 = row.CreateCell(0);
                            ICell cell2 = row.CreateCell(1);
                            ICell cell3 = row.CreateCell(2);
                            cell1.SetCellValue("Date");
                            cell2.SetCellValue("Value1");
                            cell3.SetCellValue("Value2");

                            for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++) sheet.AutoSizeColumn(i);

                            workbook.Write(fs);
                        }

                        Console.WriteLine("File is created");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        IWorkbook workbook;

                        using (var outs = new FileStream(newFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                        {
                            workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(outs);
                            outs.Close();
                            Console.WriteLine("Workbook read");
                        }

                        ISheet sheet = workbook.GetSheetAt(0);
                        IRow row = sheet.CreateRow(sheet.LastRowNum+1);
                        ICell cell1 = row.CreateCell(0);
                        ICell cell2 = row.CreateCell(1);
                        ICell cell3 = row.CreateCell(2);
                        cell1.SetCellValue(DateTime.Today.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
                        cell2.SetCellValue("Some value");
                        cell3.SetCellValue("some value 2");
                        Console.WriteLine("Values set");

                        using (var ins = new FileStream(newFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write))
                        {
                            workbook.Write(ins);
                            ins.Close();
                            Console.WriteLine("Workbook saved");

                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // We tried creating the directory and it still doesn't exist. Something is wrong, send error.
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) { Console.WriteLine(e); }
        }
```

The file is created in the correct folder but the file is 0 bytes, probably due to the various errors. Even when I did not get the errors (I'll append them further down) the files were corrupted anyway. Excel gave an error and then gave me the option to try and restore some of the data of the damaged file.

There are my errors:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in NPOI.OpenXml4Net.dll
Exception thrown: 'NPOI.POIXMLException' in NPOI.OOXML.dll
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Det går inte att läsa in filen eller sammansättningen ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib
```

I'm currently stuck. I've tried to minimize the amount of code so it only creates one cell. I did not receive errors about not finding the file previously. I'm not sure what it is it cant find, am I missing some kind of package or something?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: so, there are a few points that need to be addressed here: 1) xlsx is not a singular object its a zip package consist of several xml files in it - so, you can't just "append" stuff on an empty 0 byte file; 2) can you translate that swedish error? google translate says you are missing `ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib` package - please try reinstall all your stuffs from nuget (removing them then adding them back).

Comment: @BagusTesa Well yeah, but it's supposed to create a file with actual content in it first and then append data into it once a day.  Since the first file is corrupted this doesn't work of course.  I uninstalled SharpZipLib and re-installed it and the file creation now works. However I'm getting a new exception that pops up twice: "Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in mscorlib.dll". Btw the swedish error is "It's not possible to read the file or composition ICSharp.Code.SharpZibLib

Comment: oh right, i just realized.. your second (when the file exists) `FileStream` declaration is `FileAccess.Read`  while when the file doesn't exists, its `FileAccess.Write` on the first part. you might want to use a single using block with `FileAccess.ReadWrite` (see [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileaccess?view=net-6.0)) given `workbook` scope is for both read and write (you can't read on a closed stream). also, you could simplify the using to be only one block if you use `FileMode.OpenOrCreate` fyi.

Comment: @BagusTesa I attempted using one using block which has ReadWrite access but I got tons of errors which I did not fully understand. I'll try to replicate this and update my answer with the errors. Did you have any idea why the exception I mentioned in the previous comment comes up?